# Extract rotation values from string

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following string:

```
var foo = "rotateX(10deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(30deg) scale(1,3) skewX(90deg,0deg)"
```

How can we extract only the `rotate` values(Which here are 10,20,30)?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Answer (score 0):

"Always include in the question what you have tried."

Result will be an array of strings. You can convert to numbers if you want.

If `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ`appear in order, you can try this,

```
var arr=[];
foo.split(" ").forEach((s)=>{
    if(s.indexOf("rotate")>=0){
       arr.push(s.match(/\d/g).join(''));
    }
});
```

If order of `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ` is random. Then you can try this,

```
var arr=[null, null, null];
foo.split(" ").forEach((s)=>{
    if(s.indexOf("rotateX")>=0){
       arr[0] = s.match(/\d/g).join('');
    } else if(s.indexOf("rotateY")>=0){
       arr[1] = s.match(/\d/g).join('');
    } else if(s.indexOf("rotateZ")>=0){
       arr[2] = s.match(/\d/g).join('');
    }
});
```

Comment: @canon you mean in middle of word "rotate" ?

Comment: The code comes always in the right order.F first rotateX then rotate Y

Comment: @canon yeah you are right. If order is not `X, Y, Z`, It will give wrong answer. I didn't consider this.